# Develop application using Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK

Tags: java, cryptography, hyperledger-fabric

I'm modifying an application which uses RSA keys to encrypt and decrypt symmetric keys (which are used to encrypt files). I'm trying to substitute this feature of the central server with the Hypelredger Fabric blockchain but I found an issue: the Hypelredger Fabric tool which allows generating keys uses ECDSA algorithm. Do you have suggestions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The tools that generates keys (cryptogen) is used to generate keys for signing.
Using the same keys for signing and for encryption [is considered a bad practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig), so you should try to avoid it.

I suggest you just generate RSA keys with java, and in the chaincode (assuming you use golang chaincode) use the [crypto/rsa](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/) package.